# Java Script select option cannot show the value

Tags: javascript, laravel, drop-down-menu, dropdown, return-value

please someone help me, i've stuck in this problem.
i'm a newbie programer.
i got stuck when i try to add some dependent drop down,

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change','.kecamatan',function(e){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var kec_id=$(this).val();
        var option = '';
        $.ajax({
          type:'get',
          url:'{!!URL::to('daftar/findkecamatan')!!}',
          data:{'id':kec_id},
          success:function(data){
             for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                option += '<option value="'+ data[i].id + '">' + data[i].nama + '</option>';
            }
            $('#Desa_Kel').append(option);
        },

        error:function(){

        }
    });
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function findkecamatan(Request $request){
    $data= datadesa_kel::select('nama','id')->where('id_kecamatan',$request->id)->get();
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

and the problem is when i try to show the value to second select option

```
 for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
   option += '<option value="'+ data[i].id + '">' + data[i].nama + '</option>';
            }
 $('#Desa_Kel').append(option);
```

after get the filtered data value from controller doesn't show on the html or blade select option

**Select Option script html on blade**

```
<select class="form-control show-tick kecamatan" id="KEC" name="KEC">
    <option disabled="" selected="" value="">-- Pilih Kecamatan --</option>
    @foreach($kecamatan as $data)
    <option value="{{$data->id}}" {{old('KEC') == $data->id ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$data->nama}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
 <select class="form-control show-tick" id="Desa_Kel" name="Desa_Kel">
    <option value="0" selected disabled>-- Pilih Desa --</option>
</select>
```

**(image javascript doesn't work or cannot fill the select option [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgxFF.png))** .

```
for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
     console.log(data[i].id);
     console.log(data[i].nama);
    option += '<option value="'+ data[i].id + '">' + data[i].nama + '</option>';
            }
     $('#Desa_Kel').append(option);
```

but **when i check the data with console log in javascript it can be displayed**  on console javascript,it indicates if the data from the database works and the problem focused on why the data cannot showed on the select option ?. **please open the image below**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twNvz.png)

i am sorry if my english so bad, thank you if someone want to help me

this is when i am dd($kecamatan)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc2AR.png)

Comment: read the topic [ask] and edit your question. adding image instead of the code itself make it harder to help you.

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/984422) when asking a question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: in your blade `@foreach($kecamatan as $data)` try drop dump `$kecamatan` try this `{{dd($kecamatan)}}` what value do you get?

Comment: #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => App\datakecamatan {#1485 ▶}
    1 => App\datakecamatan {#1486 ▶}
    2 => App\datakecamatan {#1487 ▶}
@MamaWin

Comment: [This Is The result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc2AR.png).
@MamaWin

Comment: `public function daftar(){
$kecamatan= datakecamatan::all();
return view('pages/user/daftar',compact('kecamatan'));
}`
this is the script on the controller @MamaWin

Comment: wait in your option are you trying to use javascript to show the option or laravel?

Comment: i want to show the option

Comment: the problem is on the select option with ID : Desa_Kel, cannot show the result from my java script